# Find method to track duplicates

Tags: excel, vba, find, nested-loops

first time posting and hoping to get some help. :)

I have a set of data that I'm trying to go through and count the number of times there are duplicates only if certain criteria match, otherwise it should not be counted. I wrote the following which will work with smaller data sets, but when I tried with a larger data set Excel froze. My guess is due to the nest loop and having 40k entries. I realize the Find method would be better at tackling this but unable to get it working.

```
Sub pileOn()

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim k As Long

i = 1
j = 1
k = 0

Do
    Do
        If ((Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 21).Value = _
             Worksheets("Data").Cells(j, 21).Value) And (i <> j)) Then
               If ((Worksheets("Data").Cells(j, 4).Value > _
                   Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 4).Value) And _
                   (Worksheets("Data").Cells(j, 16).Value < _
                    Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 16).Value)) Then

                  k = k + 1

               End If
        End If

        j = j + 1

    Loop Until IsEmpty(Worksheets("Data").Cells(j, 21))

    i = i + 1
    j = 1

Loop Until IsEmpty(Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 21))

Worksheets("Results").Cells(1, 2).Value = k

End Sub
```

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Your processing will be much faster if you read the whole range into a variant array and work on that, instead of accessing the worksheet to read every cell.

Answer (score 0):

I got around this by using the scripting dictionary to perform the check and then highlight any rows found:

```
Sub DupeChecker()
    ' setup the selection
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Select

    ' now check that row for dupes, and flag each dupe with some formatting
    Dim d As Object, e
    Set d = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    For Each e In Intersect(Columns(ActiveCell.Column), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
        If e.Value <> vbNullString Then
            If Not d.exists(e.Value) Then d(e.Value) = 1 Else _
                e.Font.ColorIndex = 4
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

You can then test for highlighting to count up your dupes:

```
If ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, "A").Font.ColorIndex = 4 then
    MsgBox("duplicate text in A1!")
End If
```

I lifted this code from MrExcel forums a while ago, so all credit to mirabeau!

Comment: This is a great jumping off point! I'm a big fan of using `Collection`-type objects for dupe-checking. That being said, I think this response could use a bit more fleshing out -- for example, the original question is not only checking for dupes in column 21, but is also looking at values in column 4 and column 16.

Comment: Ohh ok Dan... You're right hehehe

So to continue to implement the original functionality, you could put some more tricks in the for loop:

'For Each e In Intersect(Columns(ActiveCell.Column), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
        If e.Value <> vbNullString Then
            If Not d.exists(e.Value) Then d(e.Value) = 1 Else _
                e.Font.ColorIndex = 4
                If e.Value > d.Value then
        End If
    Next'

                     
Oh man! I didn't know the comment markdown was so different! i'll come back with another answer...

Answer (score 0):

I pulled together a `pileOn2` script in the vein of Tim's recommendation... variant arrays offer great speed when facing a large number of comparisons:

```
Option Explicit
Sub pileOn2()

Dim i As Long, j As Long, Dupes As Long, _
    LastRow As Long
Dim wsData As Worksheet
Dim rTemp As Range
Dim dCol() As Variant, pCol() As Variant, _
    uCol() As Variant

'set references up front
Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
With wsData
    LastRow = .Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
End With
Set rTemp = Range(wsData.Cells(1, 4), wsData.Cells(LastRow, 4))
dCol = rTemp
Set rTemp = Range(wsData.Cells(1, 16), wsData.Cells(LastRow, 16))
pCol = rTemp
Set rTemp = Range(wsData.Cells(1, 21), wsData.Cells(LastRow, 21))
uCol = rTemp
i = 1
j = 1
Dupes = 0

'find occurrences where:
'(1) dupe value for i and j in column 21
'(2) value in j > i in column 4
'(3) value in j < i in column 16
For i = 1 To LastRow
    For j = 1 To LastRow
        If uCol(i, 1) = uCol(j, 1) And dCol(j, 1) > dCol(i, 1) And pCol(j, 1) < pCol(i, 1) Then
            Dupes = Dupes + 1
        End If
    Next j
Next i

'write duplicate count out
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Results").Cells(1, 2) = Dupes

End Sub
```